# Can Dispater take Invocation items?

Tags: nethack

After several years of playing, I thought I had seen most every monster in NH343 until now.  As I was fighting Rodney to retrieve the Candelabra and Bell he stole (at least I think he did), he summoned nasties. I killed Rodney and all the others, but couldn't find the items.  I then found Dispater at the up stair through blind ESP (no one else to be found) and checked the wiki about him (not much there, except very dangerous).  Assuming he had them, I ended up dying surrounded by nasties, but still don't know if he had the items. Can he take the items (also, any helpful info about fighting him would be appreciated)?

Answer (score 2):

No, Dispater only covets the Amulet of Yendor, not the invocation items.